# Do some Americans in the Midwest pronounce "sorry" similarly to Canadians?

Tags: american-english, pronunciation, north-american-english, canadian-english

I just listened to the closing arguments from the defense team in the Kyle Rittenhouse trial. At one point, Mr. Rittenhouse’s lawyer pronounced the word “sorry” in a way that to my non-native ears strongly resembled the way many Canadians pronounce it (think of the “stereotypical Canadian” way).

[Here](https://youtu.be/tY678KVdFpg?t=994) you can hear the defence attorney twice pronouncing *car **source** three*.

According to *The New York Times*, Kyle Rittenhouse’s defense lawyer is Mark Richards, “a Wisconsin native,” who “has spent his career in Kenosha and Racine, Wis.” (https://www.nytimes.com/2021/11/02/us/rittenhouse-defense-lawyer-mark-richards.html).

Do some U.S. English speakers in the Midwest share this pronunciation feature with Canadian English? I was reminded that another well-known Canadianism, the use of “eh,” is actually also used in parts of the American Midwest. Maybe something similar is at play here.

Comment: Wisconsin borders Manitoba and Ontario, so I wouldn't be surprised if they have like accents.

Comment: Could you please provide a link to somewhere that would allow the rest of us to hear exactly what you're referencing here? I'm from there myself. For *sorry* we usually use the tense vowel from *so* except that it's a monophthong before R. It never sounds like *sari*, the garment from India that uses the unrounded FATHER vowel. These monophthong versions of tense O and E especially before R are quite common throughout the Upper Midwest, and reasonably well documented as such. You may also from time to time hear it said with the more lax vowel of *saw*; however it's still rounded either way.

Comment: @tchrist I can't quite get myself to listen through a very long closing argument in order to find exactly that point (I think I heard it in a video excerpt in a NYT article). But in any case, it was meant more as an illustrative example to a general question, the question of whether speakers in Canada and the Midwest share this pronunciation feature, and was aimed at anyone who might have some knowledge of this; the question was not seeking commentary on this specific speaker's pronunciation or dialect.

Comment: Then you can't get an answer because you haven't been able to show us what it sounds like. Nobody knows your accent bias, and nobody knows what this "Canadian" thing is really talking about. That means your question is too unclear to be answered. Kindly edit it to make this possible. And no, @GEdgar, you aren't going to find that many Wisconsin accents sound like they're from Ontario or Manitoba.

Comment: [Here](https://youtu.be/tY678KVdFpg?t=994) you can hear the defence attorney twice pronouncing *car **source** three*.  So yes, that is the tense monophthong O before R similarly demonstrated [here for *sore*](https://soundcomparisons.com/#/en/Englishes/word/sore) as heard in such places as Canada, Ohio, Boston, Devon, and Scotland. This is merely one of the many Inland North accents, all of which do this. Please edit your question.

Answer (score -1):

The following extract from  [Dialect Blog](http://dialectblog.com/2012/01/28/im-hoarably-sorey/) appears to agree with your impression:

> In many American accents, ‘horrible,’ ‘Florida’ and ‘corridor’ are pronounced with the vowel in ‘flaw.’ But ‘sorry,’ ‘borrow’ and ‘tomorrow’ have the same vowel in ‘lot,’ as in British accents. In Canada, meanwhile, all such /or/ words have the ‘aw’ vowel, including ‘sorry.’

> What makes this even more peculiar is in the case of accents out here in the Western US, where the cot-caught merger is typical.  I can’t account for every regional accent, but my impression is that for most, sorry has the ‘short-o’ in ‘lot,’ while horrible has an entirely different ‘aw’ sound ([ɔ] or [o]).

Comment: I'm having trouble parsing the article's intent, but I *think* it's saying the opposite: that the "Canadian" pronunciation of "sorry" is mostly Canadian, and "for most" it gets the short "o". (I'm not sure what to make of the "the case of accents out here" sentence.)

Comment: Yeah, I also don't quite follow how this article "appears to agree with [my] impression."

Comment: Parts of the midwest have that pronunciation. Watch "Fargo" for the stereotypical accent.

Comment: @Barmar I don't understand what the OP is expecting to hear or not hear, nor  what they mean by “Canadian sounding”. I doubt I ever shall—until and unless they can be bothered to use real IPA. But native speakers from the Racine and Kenosha area ***do not*** have the *cot–caught* merger, and we have monophthong /o/ in *north, sorry, source, sores, wars, horrible* plus monophthong /e/ in *Mary, Harry, berry, bury, carry, scary, bears*.  Accents closer to *Fargo*’s only occur farther north in Wisconsin, like in Oshkosh's older speakers and farther north like Eau Claire, Green Bay, and Superior.

Comment: @tchrist I believe the pronunciation they're referring to sounds like "sawry" rather than "sahry".

Comment: @Barmar As I have explained, we don't have the *caught–cot* merger so we don't say that word like it's the *sari* garment from India, which sounds wrahngy to us. :)  You have to put your lips into it. You cannot get folks to understand anything you're talking about with spelling prawnancyashins and it's completely exHHausteeng to tray. It's the GOAT vowel but without the offglide that happens with the word "go", or the THOUGHT/CLOTH vowel when more relaxed. It never ever sounds like FATHER the way the *sari* Indian garment does. Sari bout thet.